# My app is freezing when I use a recylcerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on a todo app and I have a pop window opening from the bottom where the user enters the task information (description name, due date, reminder time). I use a floating action button to open the dialog. Now if I use the dialog button and hardcoded values it works fine, but with anything else it doesn't.

The code I'm using.

````
public void CreateTask(View view){
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvChild);

        EditText taskName = findViewById(R.id.txtTaskName);
        EditText taskDesc = findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);

        String task_Name = taskName.getText().toString();
        String task_desc = taskDesc.getText().toString();

        detailsList = new ArrayList<>();

        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        Details details = new Details(task_Name, task_desc);
        detailsList.add(details);

        Myadapter = new MyAdapter(detailsList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(Myadapter);
    }```

and I can see the following 2 errors in logcat


GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1



E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
````

Comment: look for a line in your LogCat logs that says "Exception" and see what it is.

Comment: @Blundell I don't see an exception in the logcat

Comment: @a_local_nobody I don't get a message that says my app crashes, it goes back to the previous activity layout and freezes

Comment: "freezes" your question says it crashes...

Comment: @Blundell Updated the question

Comment: Your question is unanswerable with the amount of information you gave. I think you can resolve this one yourself tbh

Comment: Closed my question and its not even a duplicate

Comment: Gave enough information

Comment: Read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278064/my-code-isnt-working-clarification